# Access, from Windows, files copied from Ubuntu to a media partition

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, partitioning

I have a laptop with 3 partitions on a 500gb hdd:

```
Windows 8 - 60gb - ntfs
Ubuntu 12.4 - 40gb - ext4
A media partition - 390gb - ntfs
```

I copied music files to the media partition while using Ubuntu but when I logged in to Windows I couldn't see any files there at all.

I would like to be able to access, copy and delete files on this drive partition from both operating systems.

How is this possible?

Comment: I assume you copied the files from Ubuntu's partition (ext4) to the media's partition (ntfs). Can you mount the partition in Windows? Can you see, from Ubuntu, that the files you copied are actually there?

Comment: can you explain it a bit more what you meant by media partition ? I mean which file system is it ?
Are you able to see the files in ubuntu ?
Does the media partition is visible in windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with writing data to ntfs partitions while windows 8 is suspended and not shut down (see http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html or [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)).

From your question I don't really know if this is what's happening, but when it is, the solution is properly shutting down windows 8 instead of hibernating it.

Comment: I realised later that I suspended win 8 and after restarting my laptop the files showed up in win 8 as well